# What is correct syntax of writing ID selector for select-option-selected in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For getting value from Select-Option following is syntax in jquery and i am able to get data using the same

```
$( "#Vienna\\.rail0\\.track option:selected" ).text()
```

Now problem is, I do not want to use backslash in selector and for that another way is used i.e input[id='']

Could anyone please tell me correct syntax as i tried with different styles but unable to get data:

```
$( "input[id='Vienna.rail0.track option:selected']" ).text()
$( "input[id='Vienna.rail0.track'] option:selected" ).text()
$( "input[id='Vienna.rail0.track']" + "option:selected" ).text()
```

Comment: `$( "input[id='Vienna.rail0.track'] option:selected" ).text()` This one should work!

Comment: I agree with @RajaprabhuAravindasamy. Could you include your HTML code so we can inspect further?

Comment: No. It is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is a `select` tag not an `input` tag the correct syntax is

```
   $( "select[id='Vienna.rail0.track'] option:selected" ).text()
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks. was not familiar with that. Thank you. Accepted answer:)

Comment: You are welcome, but the answer is not accepted yet :)

Comment: Yes. It was saying to wait for some minutes. :)